# Como expandir um list item no navegador mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Eu tenho o seguinte navbar no meu site:

```
<div class="navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navigation">
                <!-- Navigation Menu-->
                <ul class="navigation-menu">

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('main') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Início
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('institucional.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-building"></i> Institucional</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('simulacoes.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> Simulações </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('slides.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-image"></i> Slides</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="has-submenu">
                        <a href="{{ route('ver-imoveis.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Imóveis</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('ver-imoveis.index') }}">Ver imóveis</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('tipos.index') }}">Tipos</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ route('atributos.index') }}">Atributos</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('servicos.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>Serviços</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('depoimentos.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>Depoimentos</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('onde-estamos.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>Onde Estamos</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('configuracoes.index') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>Configurações</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Na parte de imóveis, no navegador da web, ao passar o mouse em cima, as opções de list item são expandidas.

Porém, ao acessar pelo navegador do celular, elas não se expandem. Afinal, o celular só me dá a opção de clicar e não a opção on:hover.

Como eu poderia usar o mesmo layout atual e conseguir expandir os list items clicando na opção imóveis quando eu utilizar o navegador do celular?

Comment: Adiciona pergunta o CSS e o script se tiver. Tem que ver como é controlado esse menu.

Comment: Adicione `:active` às classes com definção de `:hover`


Ex: `.sua-classe:hover, .sua-classe:active { `